# move floated div up within its parent

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

Is there a way to make .formColumn2 div move up within the parent div .bookingForm? It is float:left but I am not sure how to position it. I have tried margin. Is there a way if possible other than positioning:absolute?

---

http://jsfiddle.net/eF3am/

CSS code:

```
.bookingForm {
    height:450px;
    background-color: #D3412A;
}
.bookingForm img {
    width:200px;
    margin:90px 0 0 170px;
}
form {
    padding:20px 0 0 70px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    color:#fff;
}
.formColumn2 label {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.formColumn1,
.formColumn2{
    float:left;
}
.formColumn2 {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
select,input,textarea {
    width:200px;
    margin:8px 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to put them one atop each other?

Comment: no I only want to move .formColumn2 up.In my original code there is an image title above .formComun1 I want to align .formColumn2 with.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, posted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add `padding-top:50px` to column 1 or you can either mark column 2 with `position:relative; top:-50px;` or `margin-top:-50px;`. Those are the safest ways to make this cosmetic change :)

Let me know if you it works in your case!

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand about your question try making the parent div absolute and floated left with .formcolumn2 positioned relative, tho im not sure exactly how you would like it to look, if this doesn't work a little more detail about desired outcome would be great.

Comment: I have added a image in my post of the desired outcome